# How to use asynchronous event-handler for emitted event?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, eventemitter, blazor

I have a parent and a child component.In the child i emit an event to the parent.However i want this `Action` to be `async` since  i want the parent to perform an `async` operation when he receives the event.How can i do this ?

**Child**

```
@functions{
[Parameter] protected Action onclose { get; set; }
[Parameter] protected  Action<bool> onsubmit { get; set; } //i want this handler to be async in the parent

string campaign; 
public async Task OnSubmitAsync() {
   var created = await this.service.CreateCampaignAsync(parameters);
        Console.WriteLine("Result of creation:" + created.ToString());
        this.onsubmit?.Invoke(created);
    }
```

**Parent**

```
 <CampaignForm onclose="@(()=>OnModalClosed())" onsubmit="@(async(x)=>OnSubmit(x))"></CampaignForm>
    @functions{
       public async Task OnSubmit(bool value) {
                //do some awaiting here 
       }
       public void OnModalClose()=>....; //do something sync ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this on the child component:

```
@functions{
    // Define a property to store the Action delegate 
    [Parameter] protected  Action<bool> onsubmit { get; set; } 

    // More code here...

    public async Task OnSubmitAsync() {
   var created = await this.service.CreateCampaignAsync(parameters);
        Console.WriteLine("Result of creation:" + created.ToString());
        // Call back the parent's method
        onsubmit?.Invoke(created);
    }

 }
```

Do this on the parent component:
 Note that you should assign the identifier of the OnSubmit method to the func delegate attribute onsubmit (onsubmit="OnSubmit")

```
 <CampaignForm onclose="OnModalClosed" onsubmit="OnSubmit"></CampaignForm>
    @functions{
       public async void OnSubmit(bool value) {
                //do some awaiting here 
       }
       public void OnModalClose()=>....; //do something sync ;
    }
```

Hope this helps...
Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you out Hope this helps...

Comment: I have tried on the child with `Action<bool>` while the parent handler is `async method(bool  variable) { }` and somehow it works.

Comment: OK... After I've given it some thought I've realized that actually the Action<bool> delegate is appropriate, but I guess that the Func <bool, Task> is a better choice because it describes a delegate that has a single in parameter (bool), and an out parameter, Task. If you want to use the Action delegate, change the return type from Task to void, which is the return type for events. I'll edit my answer accordingly.